# "Missing '$' inserted" error for \left[

Tags: pdftex

I have the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{4\textsuperscript{th} Article}
\date{2023-11-03}
\author{Tejas Garhewal}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \maketitle
    
    \newpage

    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{document}
```

Which emits the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.12    \left
           (\frac{1}{x}\right)
?
```

Where exactly am I going wrong with this? I was basically following https://latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/amsmath/  when I ran into this problem with the matrix syntax, decided to shorten it to the above before posting.

Comment: `\left` (and `\frac`) need to be in math mode, so `\[\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\]`

Comment: Thank you very much, I was tearing my hair out in frustration after not being able to get the code to work even after direct copy-pasting.

Comment: the examples there will all be in `$` (inline math) or `\[..\]` (display math) `\begin{equation}`  (numbered display) etc.

Comment: It's not quite clear, but the `\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)` example on the page you linked is still under `only work within math environments as described above`.  Also, for matrices to work, you need to use a package.  I would recommend `amsmath`, which also gives you `bmatrix` and several others that would handle the brackets for you.

Comment: Oh dear... that's probably on me for wasting so much time trying to simply guess what I was doing wrong then... is there any way to get more informative error messages from latex? I'd rather not waste so much time on the next roadblock that I encounter. The command I use currently is `latex -output-format=pdf filename.tex`

Comment: The error message is quite informative, it shows the point of the error and telling you that `$\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$` would work

Comment: You could have done yourself a favor by making your example truly minimal, while still generating the error message that was tripping you up: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \end{document}`. That way, you would have been forced to focus on `\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) ` as the source of the error, and you might have realised sooner what the source of the error message was.

Comment: @Teepeemm yeah, I'm using `usepackage{amsmath}` in the file. The mistake I made was not writing tall the successive snippets of code in the same `\begin{equation*}` block and just writing in the `document` environment raw... Thanks for mentioning the`bmatrix` package, I'll use when I manage to learn enough to use latex for real work. Also, as @David mentioned, I should've been more attentive reading the error message, rather than expect the compiler to spoon-feed me what went wrong and understood from the context that a `$` at the end of the expression would've solved the issue

Comment: @Mico I knew beforehand itself that the `\left` was tripping me, I simply couldn't make myself consider that the problem was that I was not using it in the appropriate environment. From now on I will at-least enclose all mathematical expressions inside `$` before trying to investigate further.

Comment: if you just do what the error says you would add a `$` first and have `$\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)`  then run latex again and you would get another error thet there is a missing `$` at the end of the paragraph and you are still in math mode, so add a `$` where that error indicates and you would have an error free document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the tip, I'll try cooperating with the compiler next time 